# How can I get Surface View atributes from the activity? (Surface view and Activity)

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, surfaceview, appcompatactivity

I'm programming a pacman, the game is drawed in a SurfaceView, but I have problem to pause it and getting the atributes while it's running (no when I set them)

For example, I set a Semaphore that should be referenced in the Activity and in the Game view, and it is set it correct, but when the thread of the game view is running, and try to release the semaphore it indicates a NullPointerException.

On the other hand, when I try to pause the game, the game used to keep running in the background, and now when I resume it don't run

I'm sure the problem is with the references in memory, when I set and atribute as static i can access from both (view and surfaceview are the same object). I don't know why this happen.

Brief resume: An AppCompatActivity (which is PlayActivity) has a SurfaView (which is GameView), and this SurfaceView has the GameManager(which has all the things of the pacman in a moment). The references when the AppCompatActivity try to get something of the SurfaceView (for example the gameManager) are lost in execution.
Here the code

PlayActivity

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView playerNickname;
    private TextView scoreTv;
    private TextView maxScore;
    private SurfaceView gameSurfaceView;
    private GameView gameView;
    private static Semaphore CHANGE_LIFES_MUTEX=new Semaphore(0,true);
    private static Semaphore CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX=new Semaphore(0,true);
    private static Semaphore CHANGE_DIRECTION_MUTEX=new Semaphore(0,true);
    private Thread changeScoreThread, changeDirectionThread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Modified code
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        //we get text view that we will use
        playerNickname=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_player);
        scoreTv=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_score);
        maxScore=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_max_score);
        gameSurfaceView= (GameView) this.findViewById(R.id.game_view);

        //set text view initial values
        playerNickname.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("playerNickname"));
        scoreTv.setText("0");

        maxScore.setText("To modify");
        this.gameView=new GameView(gameSurfaceView.getContext());
        this.gameView.setSemaphores(CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX,CHANGE_DIRECTION_MUTEX);
        this.gameSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this.gameView);
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        this.gameView.resume();
        this.initChangerThreads();
    }

    public void updateScoreTv(int score){
        this.scoreTv.setText(""+score);
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        this.gameView.pause();
        //in order to stop the threads
        CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX.release();
        CHANGE_DIRECTION_MUTEX.release();
    }

    public void onLose(int score){
        //We try to save the score, if there is a previous register we write only if this score
        //is better that the one before
        DBManager manager;
        long raw;
        Score scoreToSave;
        manager=new DBManager(this);

        scoreToSave=new Score(this.playerNickname.toString(), score);
        if(manager.saveScore(scoreToSave)==-1){
            //if i couldn't save the score
            if(manager.updateScore(scoreToSave)!=-1){
                //if my new score is better than the one previous
            }else{
                //if my new score is worse or equal than the one previous
            }
        }

    }

    private void initChangerThreads() {
        this.changeScoreThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (gameView.isDrawing()) {
                    //Log.i("Score ",""+gameManager.getScore());
                    try {
                        CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX.acquire();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateScoreTv(gameView.getGameManager().getScore());
                            }
                        });
                    }catch (Exception e){}
                }
                Log.i("Score Thread","ended");
            }
        });
        this.changeScoreThread.start();
    }
}
```

GameView

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, SurfaceHolder.Callback, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private static final float SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 2;
    private static final float SWIPE_VELOCITY = 2;
    private static boolean CAN_DRAW = false;
    private boolean GHOST_INICIALIZED=false;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private GameManager gameManager;
    private Thread thread; //game thread
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private int blockSize;                // Ancho de la pantalla, ancho del bloque
    private static int movementFluencyLevel=8; //this movement should be a multiple of the blocksize and multiple of 4, if note the pacman will pass walls

    private int totalFrame = 4;             // Cantidad total de animation frames por direccion
    private int currentArrowFrame = 0;      // animation frame de arrow actual
    private long frameTicker;               // tiempo desde que el ultimo frame fue dibujado


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Constructors
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.constructorHelper(context);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.constructorHelper(context);
    }

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.constructorHelper(context);

    }

    private void constructorHelper(Context context) {
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        this.holder = getHolder();
        this.holder.addCallback(this);
        this.frameTicker = (long) (1000.0f / totalFrame);

        this.gameManager=new GameManager();

        int screenWidth=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        this.blockSize = ((((screenWidth/this.gameManager.getGameMap().getMapWidth())/movementFluencyLevel)*movementFluencyLevel)/4)*4;
        this.holder.setFixedSize(blockSize*this.gameManager.getGameMap().getMapWidth(),blockSize*this.gameManager.getGameMap().getMapHeight());

        this.gameManager.getGameMap().loadBonusBitmaps(this.getBlockSize(),this.getResources(),this.getContext().getPackageName());
        this.gameManager.setPacman(new Pacman("pacman","",this.movementFluencyLevel,this.gameManager.getGameMap().getPacmanSpawnPosition(),this.blockSize,this.getResources(),this.getContext().getPackageName()));

        Ghost.loadCommonBitmaps(this.blockSize,this.getResources(),this.getContext().getPackageName());
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Getters and setters
    public int getBlockSize() {
        return blockSize;
    }
    public GameManager getGameManager() {
        return gameManager;
    }
    public boolean isDrawing(){
        return CAN_DRAW;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private synchronized void initGhost(){
        if(!GHOST_INICIALIZED){
            GHOST_INICIALIZED=true;
            this.gameManager.initGhosts(this.blockSize,this.getResources(),this.getContext().getPackageName(),movementFluencyLevel);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long gameTime;
        Canvas canvas;
        while (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        }
        this.initGhost();
        this.setFocusable(true);
        while (CAN_DRAW) {
            gameTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(gameTime > frameTicker + (totalFrame * 15)){
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if(canvas!=null){
                    if(this.updateFrame(gameTime,canvas)){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        }catch (Exception e){}
                    }
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    if(this.gameManager.checkWinLevel()){
                        CAN_DRAW=false;
                        this.gameManager.cancelThreads();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                        //animation
                        Log.i("Game","You win");
                    }else if(!this.gameManager.getPacman().hasLifes()){
                        //we lost

                        CAN_DRAW=false;
                        this.gameManager.cancelThreads();

                        //animation
                        Log.i("Game","You lose");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Method to capture touchEvents
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //To swipe
        //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32rSs4tE-mc
        this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    //Chequea si se deberia actualizar el frame actual basado en el
    // tiempo que a transcurrido asi la animacion
    //no se ve muy rapida y mala
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private boolean updateFrame(long gameTime, Canvas canvas) {
        Pacman pacman;
        Ghost[] ghosts;
        boolean pacmanIsDeath;

        pacman=this.gameManager.getPacman();
        ghosts=this.gameManager.getGhosts();

        // Si el tiempo suficiente a transcurrido, pasar al siguiente frame
        frameTicker = gameTime;
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.gameManager.getGameMap().draw(canvas, Color.BLUE,this.blockSize,this.gameManager.getLevel());
        this.gameManager.moveGhosts(canvas,this.blockSize);
        pacmanIsDeath=pacman.move(this.gameManager,canvas);

        if(!pacmanIsDeath){
            // incrementar el frame
            pacman.changeFrame();
            for(int i=0; i<ghosts.length;i++){
                ghosts[i].changeFrame();
            }
            currentArrowFrame++;
            currentArrowFrame%=7;
        }else{
            pacman.setNextDirection(' ');
            for(int i=0; i<ghosts.length;i++){
                ghosts[i].respawn();
            }
        }
        return pacmanIsDeath;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return this.getGameManager().getScore();
    }

    public void setSemaphores(Semaphore changeScoreSemaphore, Semaphore changeDirectionSemaphore){
        this.gameManager.setChangeScoreSemaphore(changeScoreSemaphore);
        this.gameManager.getPacman().setChangeDirectionSemaphore(changeDirectionSemaphore);
        Log.i("Semaphore", "setted");
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Callback methods
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        CAN_DRAW = true;
        this.thread= new Thread(this);
        this.thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i("Surface","destroyed");
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void resume() {
        CAN_DRAW = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        CAN_DRAW = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // retry
            }
            break;
        }
        this.thread=null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent downEvent, MotionEvent moveEvent, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        //To swipe
        //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32rSs4tE-mc
        boolean result;
        float diffX, diffY;
        Pacman pacman;
        Log.i("Fling", "detected");

        result=false;
        diffX = moveEvent.getX() - downEvent.getX();
        diffY = moveEvent.getY() - downEvent.getY();
        pacman=this.gameManager.getPacman();

        if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY){
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    //right
                    pacman.setNextDirection('r');
                } else {
                    //left
                    pacman.setNextDirection('l');
                }
            }else{
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    //down
                    pacman.setNextDirection('d');
                } else {
                    //up
                    pacman.setNextDirection('u');
                }
            }
            result=true;
        }
        return result;
    }

}


GameManager
public class GameManager {
    private static final int TOTAL_LEVELS=256;
    private static int SCORE=0;
    private GameMap gameMap;
    private int level,bonusResetTime;//,score;
    private CountDownScareGhosts scareCountDown;
    private Pacman pacman;
    private Ghost[] ghosts;
    private boolean fruitHasBeenInTheLevel;
    private static Semaphore CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX;

    public GameManager(){
        this.fruitHasBeenInTheLevel=false;
        //this.score=0;
        this.gameMap=new GameMap();
        this.gameMap.loadMap1();
        this.level=1;
        this.ghosts=new Ghost[4];
        this.bonusResetTime = 5000;
        this.scareCountDown=null;
    }

    public void setChangeScoreSemaphore(Semaphore changeScoreSemaphore) {
        CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX = changeScoreSemaphore;
        //if(this.changeScoreSemaphore==null){
        //    Log.i("Change Score Semaphore","I'm null");
        //}else{
        //    Log.i("Change Score Semaphore","I'm not null");
        //}
    }

    public void addScore(int s){
        //this.score+=s;
        SCORE+=s;
        CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX.release();
        /*if(this.changeScoreSemaphore==null){
            Log.i("Change Score Semaphore","I'm null");
        }else{
            Log.i("Change Score Semaphore","I'm not null");
        }*/
        //this.changeScoreSemaphore.release();
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return SCORE;
        //return this.score;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return this.level;
    }
    public GameMap getGameMap() {
        return this.gameMap;
    }
    public Ghost[] getGhosts(){
        return this.ghosts;
    }
    public Pacman getPacman(){
        return this.pacman;
    }
    public void setPacman(Pacman pacman){
        this.pacman=pacman;
    }


    public void eatPallet(int posXMap, int posYMap){
        SCORE+=10;
        CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX.release();
        //this.score+=10;
        Log.i("Score GM", ""+SCORE);
        //Log.i("Score GM", ""+this.score);
        this.gameMap.getMap()[posYMap][posXMap]=0;
        //this.changeScoreSemaphore.release();
        //if(this.changeScoreSemaphore==null){
        //    Log.i("Change Score Semaphore","I'm null");
        //}else{
        //    Log.i("Change Score Semaphore","I'm not null");
        //}
    }

    public void eatBonus(int posXMap,int posYMap){
        SCORE+=500;
        CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX.release();
        //this.score+=500;
        //Log.i("Score", Double.toString(this.score).substring(0,Double.toString(this.score).indexOf('.')));
        this.gameMap.getMap()[posYMap][posXMap]=0;
        //this.changeScoreSemaphore.release();
    }

    public void eatSuperPallet(int posXMap,int posYMap){
        SCORE+=50;
        CHANGE_SCORE_MUTEX.release();
        //this.score+=50;
        this.gameMap.getMap()[posYMap][posXMap]=0;

        //Si hay un timer andando lo cancelo y ejecuto otro
        if (this.scareCountDown != null){
            this.scareCountDown.cancel();
        }
        this.scareCountDown = new CountDownScareGhosts(this.ghosts,this.gameMap.getMap());
        this.scareCountDown.start();
        //this.changeScoreSemaphore.release();
    }

    public void tryCreateBonus(){
        //only if pacman has eaten 20 pallets we should allow the fruit appear
        if(!this.fruitHasBeenInTheLevel && this.gameMap.getEatenPallets()>=20){
            //to not allow the fruit be again in the level
            this.fruitHasBeenInTheLevel=true;
            new CountdownBonusThread(this.gameMap,this.bonusResetTime).start();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void moveGhosts(Canvas canvas,int blocksize) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ghosts.length; i++) {
            ghosts[i].move(this.gameMap.getMap(),this.pacman);
            ghosts[i].draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void initGhosts(int blocksize, Resources res, String packageName,int movementFluency) {
        int[][]spawnPositions,cornersPositions, notUpDownPositions,defaultTargets;

        defaultTargets=this.gameMap.getDefaultGhostTarget();
        notUpDownPositions=this.gameMap.getNotUpDownDecisionPositions();
        spawnPositions=this.gameMap.getGhostsSpawnPositions();
        cornersPositions=this.gameMap.getGhostsScatterTarget();
        //start position
        // 5 blinky spawn [13, 11]
        // 6 pinky spawn [15,11]
        // 7 inky spawn [13,16]
        // 8 clyde spawn [15,16]
        this.ghosts=new Ghost[4];
        ghosts[0] = new Ghost("blinky",spawnPositions[0], cornersPositions[0] ,new BehaviorChaseAgressive(notUpDownPositions,movementFluency,defaultTargets[0]),movementFluency,notUpDownPositions,'l',defaultTargets[0],blocksize,res,packageName);
        ghosts[1] = new Ghost("pinky",spawnPositions[1],cornersPositions[1],new BehaviorChaseAmbush(notUpDownPositions,movementFluency,defaultTargets[1]),movementFluency,notUpDownPositions,'r',defaultTargets[1],blocksize,res,packageName);
        ghosts[2] = new Ghost("inky",spawnPositions[2],cornersPositions[2],new BehaviorChasePatrol(notUpDownPositions,this.ghosts[0],movementFluency,defaultTargets[0]),movementFluency,notUpDownPositions,'l',defaultTargets[0],blocksize,res,packageName);
        ghosts[3] = new Ghost("clyde",spawnPositions[3],cornersPositions[3],new BehaviorChaseRandom(notUpDownPositions,cornersPositions[3],movementFluency,defaultTargets[1]),movementFluency,notUpDownPositions,'r',defaultTargets[1],blocksize,res,packageName);

        try{
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }catch(Exception e){}

        for (int i=0;i<ghosts.length;i++){
            ghosts[i].onLevelStart(1);
        }

    }

    public boolean checkWinLevel() {
        //player win the level if he has eaten all the pallet
        return this.gameMap.countPallets()==0;
    }

    public void onResume(){
        for (int i=0 ; i<this.ghosts.length;i++){
            this.ghosts[i].cancelBehavoirThread();
        }
        if(this.scareCountDown!=null && !this.scareCountDown.hasEnded()){
            this.scareCountDown.start();
        }
    }

    public void onPause(){
        for (int i=0 ; i<this.ghosts.length;i++){
            this.ghosts[i].cancelBehavoirThread();
        }
        if(this.scareCountDown!=null && !this.scareCountDown.hasEnded()){
            this.scareCountDown=this.scareCountDown.onPause();
        }
    }

    public void cancelThreads(){
        for (int i=0 ; i<this.ghosts.length;i++){
            this.ghosts[i].cancelBehavoirThread();
        }
        if(this.scareCountDown!=null){
            this.scareCountDown.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the NPE happening, in ``GameManager``? Does it help if you set the mutex variables in ``GameManager`` as ``volatile``? You're setting the value (through ``setSemaphores``) on the main thread, but your game loop is running on a different thread, so it might not see those changes